# Ionic 2: Is there a hook for when scroll-content is sized correctly?

Tags: angular, ionic2

The scroll-content element is the full height of the viewport, minus the height of the toolbar. I need get the height of the scroll-content element using JavaScript, but the height of the toolbar itself is subtracted using JavaScript at some point in Ionic's rendering of the template, after about 100ms. I'm looking for a hook which would be called when the scroll-content element is done resizing.

Comment: The last view lifecycle event to fire is `ionViewDidEnter`. If the calculation isn't done at that point, then I don't think there's an event for it.

Comment: There might be a scroll event to listen to, I can't seem to find doc pages though.